# Creating Downloadable Output of XML file with ancient PHP 4 version

Tags: php, mysql, xml, output

I work with MySQL database. I want to view the output of my query as a downloadable xml file. I can't use SimpleXML or XMLWriter because I use the php 4.

Could you help me to find the way.I should say that the data is layered and dependant in each other?

Comment: well you just need to build the xml manually, just like the you did with the html table, using loops

Comment: could you give me a sample example?

Answer (score 3):

Update your PHP version to something that didn't die more then [six years ago](http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: I couldn't do that. because I am working in a company with their own rules. I know that with upper level php. I can do it easily. but my question is that without this how I CAN DO IT.

Comment: @user2011036: That's fine. Just tell your company that you can not use *common* support material from the internet, for example sites like Stackoverflow or even php.net (apart from the museum section - you won't even find sources on http://lxr.php.net/ any longer) for your development needs. That means: Extra pay for the extra hard work you do there every day. And if you can't on that time that has been budgeted to you: Plus the budget you need to find somebody else to work for that company doing the research in software archaeology. Own Rules. Play them.